# Java BigInteger testBit 64-bit long

Tags: java, binary, long-integer, biginteger

This is probably a silly question, but I can't seem to find a simple answer.

I'm reading in a 64-bit (8 byte) `long` value and I'm then trying to use the `BigInteger.testBit` to see if bit 63 is set, as it's being used as a flag.

```
long value = 0x4000863; //This value is actually read from a file
Long.toBinaryString(value) = 100000000000000100001100011
BigInteger test = new BigInteger(Long.toString(value));
if (test.testBit(63)) {
    //yay
}
else {
    //boo
}
```

The above code is what I'm currently trying, and it says bit 63 is not set.  As it's being stored as a long, I didn't think I'd have to pad the value, or am I just doing something wrong entirely?

Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for bit 26 - not 63.

Comment: Not too familiar with this topic, but why would it be set? The first 1 in 100000000000000100001100011 is bit 26.

Comment: That's because it *isn't* set. The one on the far right is bit 0.

Comment: I see that, but why is the value only 27 bits long, it's read as an 8 byte long, so I need to pad it or something?

Comment: @Tony because toBinaryString doesn't add leading zeroes at the front (same way that Long.toString(value) doesn't return 0000000000067111011)

Comment: It's not, `toBinaryString` probably removes all leading zeros.

Comment: OK, I now understand that toBinaryString is probably not printing the leading zeroes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting the bits wrong:

```
public void test() {
    // Binary - 100000000000000100001100011
    //          ^ This is bit 26
    long value = 0x4000863; 
    // Binary - ‭1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000‬
    //          ^ THIS is bit 63
    long bigger = 0x8000000000000000L;
    BigInteger test = new BigInteger(Long.toString(value));
    System.out.println("L:" + Long.toBinaryString(value) + "\r\nB:" + test.toString(2) + "\r\nB63:" + test.testBit(63));
    test = new BigInteger(Long.toString(bigger));
    System.out.println("L:" + Long.toBinaryString(bigger) + "\r\nB:" + test.toString(2) + "\r\nB63:" + test.testBit(63));
}
```